# How to list became parameter in method put?

Tags: java, list, dictionary, arraylist, jdbc

I want to send data from the list as input to execute a stored procedure. In code below, all variable list which contains to be sent as an input parameter.

```
public void onClick$btnSend() throws Exception {
    Workbook workbook = new Workbook("D:/excel file/Mapping Prod Matriks _Group Sales Commercial.xlsx");
    com.aspose.cells.Worksheet worksheet = workbook.getWorksheets().get(0);
    com.aspose.cells.Cells cells = worksheet.getCells();
    Range displayRange = cells.getMaxDisplayRange();
    List<String> ParaObjGroup = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> ParaObjCode = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> ParaProdMatrixId = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> ParaProdChannelId = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> ParaProdSalesGroupId = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> ParaCustGroup = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> ParaSlsThroughId = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<Integer> Active = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for(int row= displayRange.getFirstRow()+1;row<displayRange.getRowCount();row++){
        ParaObjGroup.add(displayRange.get(row,1).getStringValue());
        ParaObjCode.add(displayRange.get(row,3).getStringValue());
        ParaProdMatrixId.add(displayRange.get(row,5).getStringValue());
        ParaProdChannelId.add(displayRange.get(row,7).getStringValue());
        ParaProdSalesGroupId.add(displayRange.get(row,9).getStringValue());
        ParaCustGroup.add(displayRange.get(row,11).getStringValue());
        ParaSlsThroughId.add(displayRange.get(row,13).getStringValue());
        Active.add(displayRange.get(row,14).getIntValue());
    }

    System.out.println(ParaObjGroup);
    System.out.println(ParaObjCode);
    System.out.println(ParaProdMatrixId);
    System.out.println(ParaProdChannelId);
    System.out.println(ParaProdSalesGroupId);
    System.out.println(ParaCustGroup);
    System.out.println(ParaSlsThroughId);
    System.out.println(Active);

    lovService.coba(ParaObjGroup,ParaObjCode,ParaProdMatrixId,ParaProdChannelId,ParaProdSalesGroupId,ParaCustGroup,ParaSlsThroughId,Active);

        }
```

and below code for execute stored procedure

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = {SQLException.class, Exception.class })
public void executeSPForInsertData(DataSource ds,String procedureName,Map<String[], Object[]> inputParameter){
    SimpleJdbcCall jdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(paramsDataSourceBean).withProcedureName(procedureName);
    jdbcCall.execute(inputParameter);
}
```

But I have a problem cannot set the list type as a parameter in method `put`:

```
@ServiceLog(schema = ConstantaVariable.DBDefinition_Var.PARAMS_DB_SCHEMA, sp = ConstantaVariable.PARAMSProcedure_VAR.PR_SP_FAHMI)
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor={Exception.class,SQLException.class})
public void coba(List<String> params1,List<String> params2,List<String> params3,List<String> params4,List<String> params5,
        List<String> params6,List<String> params7,List<Integer> params8){
    Map<String[], Object[]> mapInputParameter = new LinkedHashMap<String[], Object[]>();
    mapInputParameter.put("P_OBJT_GROUP", params1);
    mapInputParameter.put("P_CODE", params2);
    mapInputParameter.put("P_PROD_MATRIX_ID", params3);
    mapInputParameter.put("P_PROD_CHANNEL_ID", params4);
    mapInputParameter.put("P_PROD_SALES_GROUP_ID", params5);
    mapInputParameter.put("P_CUST_GROUP", params6);
    mapInputParameter.put("P_SLS_THROUGH_ID", params7);
    mapInputParameter.put("P_ACTIVE", params8);
    ParamsService.getService().executeSPForInsertData(null,ConstantaVariable.PARAMSProcedure_VAR.PR_SP_FAHMI,mapInputParameter);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The type `Map<String[], Object[]>` is not compatible with what you try to put in: The key is `String` and the value is `List<String>`.

There are two solutions:

1. Change the map to be compatible with the inserted parameters.

   ```
   Map<String, List<String>> mapInputParameter = new LinkedHashMap<>();
   ```
2. If you need to use the original map type, then you have to change the way you put the parameters into the map.

   ```
   Map<String[], Object[]> mapInputParameter = new LinkedHashMap<>();
   mapInputParameter.put(new String[] { "P_OBJT_GROUP" }, new Object[] { params1 });
   mapInputParameter.put(new String[] { "P_CODE" }, new Object[] { params2 });
   ```

   The drawback is that in further processing you have to check if the array is not empty and cast explicitly from `Object` to `List<String>`.

If you want something "more universal and more generic", I'd go for `Map<String, List<Object>>`. In any way, I find no reason to use an array in the map unless it is explicitly required (I have no information about the `executeSPForInsertData` method.